# Rally web service API: Retrieve Test Cases base on Iteration or WorkProduct attributes

Tags: rally

I try to retrieve test cases from rally using XML URL such as
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/testcase?query = ...

I want to retrieve only test cases of WorkProducts those are accepted from day x to day y so I build the query like this:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/testcase?query=((WorkProduct.AcceptedDate >= "yyyy-mm-dd") AND (WorkProduct.AcceptedDate <= "yyyy-mm-dd"))
The result is: Could not traverse to "AcceptedDate"

The funny thing is I can do something like:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/testcase?query=(WorkProduct.LastUpdateDate <= "2012-06-26")
which is the same concept.

Is there anyone can say why LastUpdate information is query-able and AcceptedDate is not?

Thanks,
Minh Tue

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because the WorkProduct field on TestCase is an Artifact.  Artifact does have a LastUpdateDate field but does not have an AcceptedDate field.  You should still be able to get the data you want but it will take a few extra queries.

You'll have to query for defects and stories whose AcceptedDate is in the desired range and include TestCases in the fetch.

Comment: This is the good hint Kyle! The challenge is fetching test case's fields like FormattedID, Type,etc. starting from its WorkProduct (defect or hierachicalrequirement). This is really challenge!

Comment: Fetch will include sub-object fields that are not even on the main type.  So for example in this instance fetching FormattedID would populate both the field of both the main story and any of its test cases.  Fetching LastVerdict is valid even though stories don't have that field.

Comment: It is not, Kyle. I tried many times and the deepest that it could be fetch is the ref URI to each test cases that a user story has. I dont think Rally supports recursive fetching! :-(